# How to display 4 items in one row and 4 in second row and so on...?

Tags: php, wordpress

So what i need is to have this vertical_align div where i display 4x col-md-3 and then display in next div vertical_align next 4x col-md-3 and so on?

```
<?php 
  foreach ($images as $image) {
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
   ?>
        <div class="vertical_align">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes ?>" alt=""/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
                 $count++;
               ?>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
```

Comment: `if  ($count % 4 ==0) { start new row }`

Comment: how will i say that "start new row"?

Comment: There are some missing `php` code parts before and after your example that mess the colored parts of it, could you add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below code to close the div and open a new div for each 4 items.

```
<div class="vertical_align"">
<?php foreach ($images as $image) {
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="">
                <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes ?>" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
             $count++;
             // if reaches 4 items close the div and open a new div
             if($count % 4 ==0){?>
                </div> 
                <div class="vertical_align"">
            <?php  }     
     }?>
</div>
```

You can change the value to any number by replace 4 to any number.